# firebase serve attach debugger with VS Code

Tags: firebase, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-functions

i am using `firebase serve --only functions,hosting` command to run emulator locally. This works fine. But I would like to take further step, and would like to debug my functions locally with debugger attached. Url example: http://localhost:5001/foo-project/us-central1/helloWorld

Is it possible to do so?

How can I build launch.json to attach debugger to  my functions?

```
   {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach",
      "port": 9229
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Set your launch.json like this:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/functions/index.js",
      "env": { "FIREBASE_CONFIG": "{\"databaseURL\":\"https://XXXXX-2d371.firebaseio.com\",\"storageBucket\":\"XXXXX-2d371.appspot.com\",\"projectId\":\"XXXX-2d371\"}"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Be sure to set your "program" to your starting point of your functions directory.